# Wordress search does not find Woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce shop and I faced with a problem. The Wordpress search page does not show the products. The products are found only in the search bar ajax.
As I found, the problem is with the search quary url. Look at the following links:

`https://kabulbooks.com/?s=نگاه`

`https://kabulbooks.com/?s=نگاه&post_type=product`

The first url does not find the products but the second one does. So the problem is that the wordpress search does not add `&post_type=product` to the search url. I did not changed the searchform.php code and the same theme working fine in another test site.

I also deactivated all plugins, cleared the cache and updated the Woocommerce database but none of them worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you updated everything, is your theme also updated? As far as I know, the theme has some functions related to that.

Comment: @Syntax_Error Yes, everything is update.